# DecimalPad on Unity Keyboard, on Android: Recognizes Dots but Disregards Commas as Inputs

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've run into an issue with Unity's TouchScreenKeyboard when it's set to the DecimalPad type, and running on Android. Both the comma , and period . keys show up on the keyboard, but it seems like only the period is actually functional as an input. I've been trying to use the comma as a decimal separator to match the Spanish culture settings I've set for the app, but the keyboard just won't recognize the comma inputs. The keyboard.text property also never shows commas.

This is the code I am using:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.DecimalPad, false, false, false, false, "", 0);
```

Given the comma is Spain's decimal separator, the Unity keyboard not recognizing it is odd. Anyone know a fix so it accepts commas for decimals? I'm on Unity 2022.3.22f1. Thanks!